# AWS: Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore

Tags: amazon-web-services, certbot

Trying to renew letsencript on Amazon Linux 2 using certbot and I get the following message:

> Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore. Certbot cannot
> be installed.

I am totally lost and I do not know what to do. I cannot find any exhaustive documentation that gives a solution.

Comment: I am getting the same error. Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: certbot-auto is now also deprecated on Debian.

Comment: Do you have a link to this info?

Comment: certbot-auto now gives errors: `...is not suported on this system` (or alike). You need to install `certbot` package from official repos. [See here](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/install.html#operating-system-packages)

Comment: we need to build the solution, it think its too near Nov2020 when el6 hit EOL.    It needs python27 based system, and el6 is python26 in general i think.  you can put python27 on there, but run into issues still, because certbot has some kind of blocker.  

I do have one working el6 implementation using virtulenv, so maybe setup as developer for now until a better solution is found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is instructions on how to install certbot on any system:
https://certbot.eff.org/instructions

Particularly for Ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx webserver I was able to install certbot using the following commands:

```sh
snap install core
snap refresh core
snap install --classic certbot
```

Then you can run certbot using `certbot` command

Comment: this may be outdated already? their instructions are still good, then when you follow then, and install successfully, when you first run it you get this error.  also an FYI, snapd wont work on el6, its for el7/systemd i think.

Answer (score 7):

According to https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-1-9-0-release/135414 :

**Changed**
certbot-auto was deprecated on all systems except for those based on Debian or RHEL.

And from this website: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/fail-to-detect-amazon-linux-2-certbot/136140

```
The best chance to get Certbot working on Amazon Linux 2 is to install the rpm from EPEL as described here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/extending-amazon-linux-2-with-epel-and-lets-encrypt/
```

Answer (score 5):

We dropped certbot altogether on our amazon linux as we couldn't install snapd. We are using getssl (another acme client) and it is looking good. [getssl on github](https://github.com/srvrco/getssl)

Comment: Thanks to this note. I gave up on certbot and used getssl as well. I have documented my journey here in case it helps someone - https://millionclues.com/tutorials/lets-encrypt-on-amazon-aws-ec2-with-getssl/

Comment: @ArunBasilLal Thanks, that was a great writeup 

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to follow this part from [Extending Amazon Linux 2 with EPEL official docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/extending-amazon-linux-2-with-epel-and-lets-encrypt/):

```
cd /tmp
wget -O epel.rpm –nv \
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y ./epel.rpm
sudo yum install python2-certbot-apache.noarch
```

After that, `certbot renew` started to work.

Comment: I think this answer is more for an el7, where the OP i think is for an el6, where that error is generated . Your solution requires systemd, and python parts that wont exist in an el6 (centos6 anyway)

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 16.04, Let’s Encrypt client (certbot).
Reset or set up a new AWS Instance(Linux).

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot

sudo apt update

sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx
```

To check version number, run

```
certbot --version
```

Sample output:

```
certbot 0.31.0
```

#### The below command only works when port 80 is open AWS

```
sudo certbot --nginx --agree-tos --redirect --uir --hsts --staple-ocsp --must-staple -d www.example.com,example.com --email you@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

##### You'll have to install *certbot* instead of *certbot-auto*

The official certbot docs recommend installing it using `snapd` but unfortunately you cannot install snapd on Amazon Linux 2 due to some missing `selinux` dependencies

##### You have 2 options at this point

###### Install it using epel-extras (easier but older certbot)

- *Remove certbot-auto first*

```sh
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
sudo yum install -y certbot python-certbot-dns-route53
```

###### Install it using pip (a little complicated but you get the latest certbot)

- *Remove certbot-auto*
- *Make sure you have python3 and pip installed*

```sh
sudo python3 -m venv /opt/certbot/
sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install certbot
sudo ln -s /opt/certbot/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install certbot-dns-route53
```

Comment: And how to use it after install? How to get certificate & renew?